# How to configure proxy address for multiple WCF-bindings at once?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

To configure for proxy setup in WCF, I can solve it like this:

```
<binding name="bindingName" proxyAddress="http://proxySomething">
```

This, however, needs to be copied into every binding you have.  I wondered if there was a way to set this for **all** bindings in just one place.  Something like:

```
<proxy address="http://proxySomething" forAllBindings="true"/>
```

Is there such a setting?  I have tried searching, but could not find it.

**Update 1:** It should also be noted that I have multiple types of bindings (`basicHttpBinding`, `customBinding`, `wsHttpBinding` and `webHttpBinding`) and several named bindings for some of the types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`defaultProxy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex(v=vs.110).aspx) element from network settings:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy proxyaddress="http://someproxy:8080"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

More details in Info Support [blog post](https://blogs.infosupport.com/configuring-a-proxy-server-for-wcf/). 
 
Notice that this is a global proxy and [it  used by WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy(v=vs.110).aspx) instances too.

Comment: Yes!  It is almost like I have seen it before - I felt it had to be a way to set it globally.  Thanks, this works :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .net 4.5 then you can use the simplified configuration style [WCF bindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358768(v=vs.110).aspx).  this lets you configure a particular binding type and then when your client or service uses that particular binding type (say basicHttpBinding) the modified configuration will be used.

to modify the deafult binding, just don't specific a name.

so

`<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding messageEncoding="Mtom" />
  </<basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>`

Now
if you create a service using the basicHttpBinding, it will use Mtom rather than Text.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer!  This would work fine if I did not have multiple types of bindings and named bindings.  I have added an update to my question.  So even though it does not help me, it might help someone else.

Comment: @Halvard are you amicable to adding a bit of code to your solution, or does this need to be a configuration file only solution?

Comment: Web service access is spread to multiple projects.  I doubt I will be able to code anything in only one place without considerable refactoring, so I was hoping for a configuration solution.

Comment: @Halvard you might be able to create a bindingextension for each of the needed bindings.  But that sounds like its the same amount of work to config as updating the default binding settings.   The only benefit would be that you could control the proxy address as a variable from a single point in config.

Comment: Since the idea is to be able to change the proxy address in just one place for future customers, that sounds like something I could possibly use. I will try to check it out tomorrow.

Comment: As far as I can understand from the documentation on `bindingExtensions`, they can only be used to add new user-defined bindings, not change existing.  Maybe I misunderstand the documentation?  I guess this is more work than I had initially hoped for.  Thanks for your suggestions anyway!